# Do we maximize explained sum of squares with OLS?

Tags: r-squared

I know that with OLS we minimize the sum of squared residuals but does that imply that we maximize SSE? From the following r-squared formula
$$ R^2 = \frac{SSE}{SST} = 1- \frac{SSR}{SST}$$
and the fact that SST = SSE + SSR, it really seems like it is true, but I am completely sure.

Answer (score 2):

$SST = \sum_i (y_i - \bar y)^2$ is a constant that doesn't depend on your model, so doesn't change anything for optimization. If you look at the [$R^2$ definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)

$$
R^2 = 1 - \frac{SSE}{SST}
$$

you are left with $-SSE = - \sum_i (y_i - \hat y_i)^2$ that depends on the model. Maximizing the negative of the sum of squared errors is equivalent to minimizing squared error, which OLS does.

*(Notice that I corrected [the notation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/coefficient-of-determination-r-squared.html), you used $SSR$ in place of $SSE$ and vice versa.)*

Comment: I would have thought it was $R^2=1-\dfrac{SS_{\text{residuals}}}{SS_{\text{total}}}$ which is presumably where $SSR$ came from. I am not sure that *residuals* and *errors* are quite the same thing

Comment: There is also a key point that $\sum_i ( \hat y_i - \bar y)=0$ with OLS which may not apply in other models

Comment: @Henry the SSR, SST, SSE naming convention is more common, [googling for those abbreviations](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=SSE+SSR+SST) would lead to many resources using them as above.